Informatica check multiple file in windows directory
I have a task to check the multiple file in dir with same name and fail the cmd task in informatica if found duplicate files. I am able to get the duplicate file count from dir but unable to fail the task after the finding multiple files in source dir.
Below is the command I am using to get the duplicate file count. Please suggest if found duplicate file my cmd task should fail the wf.
set filescount=0 & for %f in (\abc\123.txt) do @(set /a filescount+=1 > null)

This command working fine to get the duplicate count of file. when I add count check like file count greater than 1 its not working as expected. Please help on this.
Below is the command I am using to fail a cmd task in informatica:
set filescount=0 & for %f in (\abc\123.txt) do @(set /a filescount+=1 > texfilecount & if not texfilecount == 1 EXIT 1 )

This one is not working as expected.

Instead of directing the count into a file you can directly use an if block to check the count ==1 or greater than 1
set filescount=0; for %%f in (\abc\123.txt) do @(set /a filescount+=1) if!filescount! gtr 1 ( exit 1) else (exit 0)


That command line was obviously never run by you. This command line defines an environment variable with name filescount with the string value 0; for %f in (\abc\123.txt) do @(set /a filescount+=1) if!filescount! gtr 1 ( exit 1) else (exit 0) as it can be seen on executing after this command line in a command prompt window next the command line set filescount.
